# How to get next level data from JSON with Ember template

Tags: javascript, templates, ember.js

I have this json data:

```
[
    {
        "id" : "1",
        "data" : {
            "name": "Lukas"
        }
    }   
]
```

and i try to reach `name` value so i do this

```
{{data.name}}
```

but it dos't work. If i call for id, id will displayed. Can anybody help?

Comment: Could you provide more detail and/or a jsBin or jsFiddle?

Comment: what for? i need to appeal to name value by handelbars template, this is clear, i guess

Comment: Yes, but without context it is pretty impossible to help you

Comment: Did you manage to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

That normally works fine - see [this jsBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/novof/1/) for an example

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
   ID: {{id}}
   Name: {{data.name}}    
</script>
```

Javascript:

```
var data = {
   "id" : "1",
   "data" : {
      "name": "Lukas"
   }
};

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function() {
      return data;
   }
});
```